# how to pass arguments like 750_000 from command line

Tags: literals, argv, perl

I am unable to pass values like `750_000` from command line to a function like `usleep` via shift. Still getting ".. isn't numeric".

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `750_000` syntax is valid for [numeric literals](https://perldoc.pl/perldata#Scalar-value-constructors) in source code, where it is simply ignored when populating the value. It is not valid when using a string that's already been created (such as read from commandline arguments) as a number. Numbers can be stored in strings with scientific notation as you noted. Alternatively you could remove the underscores yourself:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::HiRes 'usleep';
my $num = shift;
$num =~ tr/_//d;
usleep $num;
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I have chosen your version of answer as the 'Answer' as it provides clearer explanation of the ask.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but answering my own question.

It can be done using exponent syntax.

examples:

1. `1_000_000` can be written as `1e6`
2. `1_234_567` can be written as
   `1.234567e6`

Comment: What's the point of writing `1.234567e6` when you could just use `1234567`?

Comment: @melpomene: You are right - It works like that as well. Stupid me that I didn't think of it. Thanks for highlighting.